# How to calculate amplitude from a wav file?

Tags: audio, python, audio-processing, amplitude

I'm a beginner in audio signal processing, and trying to calculate the amplitude of a .wav file. I've read some documents from the web and some other questions asked about this topic. However, I still don't know how to calculate the amplitude and sum of the amplitude contour (in dB) from a .wav file in Python. Hope someone can help.

Comment: It depends on the type and range of the values in wav file. Or the library you use to load the wav file, which may convert it for you. How do you load the wav file?

Comment: Most Wav files just contain PCM-encoded audio. In other words, whatever you load from the file *is* amplitude values. From the first to the last sample.

Comment: @Justme I load the wav file using librosa tool.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Do you mean y in ` y, sr = librosa.load("try.wav")`?

Comment: yeah, in the result of that, `y` contains instantaneous amplitude samples.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Okay, then how about amplitude ?

Comment: Every value in `y` is an amplitude value. I don't understand what you mean with "how about amplitude?".

Comment: Oh! REALLY??? I thought it needs more calculation or fft transform...

Comment: I've been saying this three times now, explicitly...

Answer (score 1):

A wave file contains the instantaneous amplitude of the sound signal as series of time domain samples. The most common format is 16-bit signed integer but it can also be floating point, 32-bit integer, etc. I can have one or more channels. For example, stereo will have left and right channels.

`librosa.load()` has a lot of options to manipulate the data during the loading process, so I recommend carefully looking at those and pick what's required for your application.

In most (but not all) cases you will end up with a series of floating point numbers that are between -1.0 and +1.0. There is no direct connection too the original amplitude of the sound signal unless you have external calibration information, so you cannot reconstruct the original sound level.

> I still don't know how to calculate amplitude and sum of the amplitude contour (in dB) from a wav file in Python.

I have no idea what this is supposed to mean. Please add some more detail or some formulas or equations.